# Web scraping a table from Tennis 24

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, statistics, webhooks

Hi I am looking to periodically scrape the values from a table such as this one https://www.tennis24.com/match/Wra2Ija2/#match-statistics;0. In an ideal world I'd like to scrape when there's been a change to the page.  *(I don't know wether this is even possible to do.)*

I'm thinking to check every 3 minutes. Is this a good idea? Or is there a simpler approach?

**Also, here's my code:**
*It only pulls player Bs Aces though...*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
Chrom_path = r"C:\Users\Dan1\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chrom_path)
driver.get("https://www.tennis24.com/match/hOYDXnLI/#match-statistics;0")
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 
20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='statText 
statText--titleValue' and 
text()='Aces']//following::div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: Can you specify what all exact information do you want to scrap from the website as in the question description it is not clear at all.

Comment: hi its the in play statistics table values which I would like to scrape every time the data in the table changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the table has an iterated pattern with the tag `<div class="statTextGroup">`

which contains 3 child nodes :

`<div class="statText statText--homeValue">0</div>`

`<div class="statText statText--titleValue">Aces</div>`

`<div class="statText statText--awayValue">7</div>`

respectively for the home player data, the label of the data, and the away player data.

My following script iterates over these nodes and print inner text content :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("../chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.tennis24.com/match/hOYDXnLI/#match-statistics;0")

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("statTextGroup")
for d in data:
    sub_data = d.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
    assert len(sub_data)==3
    for s_d in sub_data:
        print(s_d.get_attribute('class')[19:], s_d.get_attribute('innerText'))

driver.close()
```

Output displayed looks like :

```
homeValue 0
titleValue Aces
awayValue 3
homeValue 1
titleValue Double Faults
awayValue 0
homeValue 58%
titleValue 1st Serve Percentage
awayValue 62%
homeValue 60% (9/15)
titleValue 1st Serve Points Won
awayValue 45% (15/33)
homeValue 73% (8/11)
titleValue 2nd Serve Points Won
```

**Note that these data pattern is repeated 4 times (for your example) for whole game data, set 1, set 2 and set 3**

Pay attention when the data labeled "Aces" is repeated

Comment: Thats great thanks, really appreciated. as the different sets have different web adresses is there a way to just get the 1 pertaining to the web address or is this not possible?

Comment: The Array `data` is length 62. The first 17 elements refer to the whole game data, and the 3 following batch of 15 next elements are for each set. And each element of the list declines in 3 sub data for the home player data, label of data, and away player data

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate it